# File version number of .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 installer

Tags: installation, .net-3.5

I have a very large executable (237 MB) called dotnetfx35.exe.

This may be .NET 3.5, or it may be .NET 3.5 service pack 1.

How can I tell which one it is? (Short of downloading the .NET 3.5 SP1 file and doing a comparison).

On the version tab I have:

- File version: 3.5.30729.1
- Description: .NET Framework 3.5 Setup

If you have downloaded the SP1 full installer file (not the bootstrapper), could you please tell me the file version number? Then I'll know if I have to download it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What architecture is it? I have the .NET 3.5 SP1 redistributables, and their details are:

- x86: `3.5.30729.1`
- x64: `3.5.30729.1`
- IA64: `3.5.30729.1`

Hmm I see a pattern emerging here. <strike>Looks like you have the SP-1 install.</strike>

(P.S. You can this info verbosely by looking at the "Product Name" value in the Version tab of the Properties box)

**Update:** Turns out this information is not really correct. Look at the following screenshot:

[image: Dot Net 3 Point Five Version Numbers]
<sub>(source: [41085.org](http://www.41085.org/dotnetsetup.PNG))</sub>

Left = SP1 install, Right = Non-SP install. They are the same version number. I'm going to say that your version is the non-SP though, because SP1 is missing from the description according to your post.

Answer (score 2):

It is the original release of .NET 3.5.  It does not include the service packs.